# Having multiple canvas layers javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, layer

I am trying to do a paint app. But that's not all. I want to extend it with possibility of layers like in gimp or photoshop. **Some of layers can be visible and others not**. It all depends of user needs.
I tried a lot. There are some of my ideas how to do it:

1. First i tried to add new canvases to html document and changing z-index of elements. The problem of this was that addEventListener didn't know what i did. I mean that it didn't know on which layer i am actually pressing.
2. Second idea was to take of all points (vertices) of line, put it in array and then redraw it. It all will happen in area of one canvas element.
3. The last one and i think the best idea was to have multiple 2d contexts. But i don't know how to make it invisible. I saw only ctx.globalAlpha property but it needs to be configured before drawing.

Maybe someone knows what is actually the best method to achieve it. I will be very thankful for every response.

Comment: store layers as ImageData()? have a change layer. that copies changes to an otherwise ImageData() at a specified index.

Comment: @altruios it is a good idea but if you are storing imageData that is drew you are holding all of alpha pixels and you are overwriting this.